# Solve $\sin^2x=\cos x $, $x \in [0, 2\pi]$ algebraically without any calculator?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry

How do one solve this equation without a calculator?

This is what I did:

$\sin^2x=\cos x$,
$\;1-\cos^2x=\cos x$,
$\;-\cos^2x-\cos x+1=0$

Then I used the quadratic formula to solve for $\cos x$

and got

$\cos x=\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$

From here, I cannot understand how one is supposed to solve for $x$ without a calculator

Comment: The trick is to rewrite $\sin^2x$ as $1-\cos^2x$. The trick to avoiding downvotes is to show some work of your own.

Comment: It seems like you are editing your post as long as you are reading my answer

Comment: Note that a right-angled triangle with angle $x$ has three sides in geometric progression, which creates some nice sketches - some indicating an equiangular spiral - and hence a relationship with the golden ratio as others have computed (start with sides $1,a,a^2$  then $a, a^2, a^3$ etc)

Answer (score 5):

Hint:
it is just $$\sin^2x=\cos x \Longleftrightarrow 1-\cos^2x =\cos x$$

Then set $X=\cos x$ to have $$X^2 +X-1=0 \implies X=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Also note that the number $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\ge 1$ is the Golden ratio.

Comment: I actually tried this and used an expression for a quadratic expression but it became such a mess. Is this really the only solution?

Comment: @Goldname what is the point of your comment?

Comment: You don’t get nice answers like $\frac{\pi}{6}$ or something. The best you can do is express them as arccosines of specific real numbers.

Comment: @Gibbs what's the point of your question?

Comment: Guy Fsone uses $X$ instead of your $y$. What is the difference?

Comment: @Gibbs No difference other than unreadability.

Comment: @GuyFsone take a look at my answer.

Comment: The expression  $\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the inverse of Golden ratio, since we have $\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}=\frac{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}}$.

Comment: @ Guy Fsone - Yes, because $sin^2x$ is always positive, and also, $x \in [0, 2\pi]$

Comment: @Amin235 that is coll

Comment: The inverse of Golden ratio, not only satisfy equation $x^2+x-1=0$, but also holds on the equation $x^3+2x^2-1=0$.

Comment: @Amin235 has this anything to do with the original question?

Comment: @Gibbs I am thinking how the original question can be written as the equation $x^3+2x^2-1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the solution of Guy Fsone. To find $x$ (which is what you point out) you just need to apply the inverse function of $\cos$, i.e. 
$$\cos x = \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \rightarrow x_1 = \arccos \Big(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \Big) \text{ and } x_2 = 2\pi - \arccos \Big(\frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \Big).$$
Observe that $\cos x$ must be between $-1$ and $1$, so you need to rule out the solution with $-\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Is it so that since $x \in [0, 2\pi]$, then the only answer is $arccos(\frac{-1 + \sqrt5}{2})$?

Comment: Aha, thank you for pointing out that $cosx$ has to be positive also

Comment: Actually you find two solutions, because $\cos x= \alpha, 0 < \alpha < 1$ if and only if $x=\arccos \alpha$ or $x = 2\pi - \arccos \alpha$.

Comment: Yes, I understood. I wasn't clear enough when I answered your question earlier, thanks ;)

Comment: Ok +1)${}{}{}{}$

Comment: The solution with $-\sqrt{5}$ is ruled out because $-\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}<-1$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 1):

Your question (the last time I looked at it)
correctly deduces that $\cos x = \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}.$
(You can rule out the other value given by the
quadratic formula, $\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2},$ because 
$\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2} < -1$ and it is not possible for $\cos x$ to have such a value.)

The function $\arccos y$ is defined so that if $-1 \leq y \leq 1$ 
and $x = \arccos y,$
then $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ and $\cos x = y.$
For example, setting $y = \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2},$
we find that 
$$x = \arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)$$
is a solution of your equation, because
$$ \cos\left(\arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)
    \right) = \frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}.$$
This almost solves your problem, except for one detail:
the $\arccos$ function is not guaranteed to directly produce all the possible solutions,
because in general there can be many angles $x$ such that
$\cos x = y.$

Every value of $x$ such that $\cos x = y$
has one of the following two forms:
\begin{align}
x &=  2n\pi + \arccos y, & \text{$n$ an integer,} \tag1\\
x &=  2n\pi -\arccos y, & \text{$n$ an integer.} \tag2 \\
\end{align}

Your solution should include *every* possible $x$ that fits one of those two formats and that satisfies the condition $x \in [0,2\pi]$ given in the problem statement.

The solution we have so far, $x = \arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right),$
is an example of form $(1)$ with $n=0.$
Any other value of $n$ will cause the right-hand side of $(1)$ to be outside the interval $[0,2\pi],$ so we do not need to look at that form any more.

For $n = 1,$ however, $2n\pi - \arccos y \in [0,2\pi].$
So we also have a solution in form $(2)$:
$$x = 2\pi - \arccos\left(\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right).$$